# Why is code appended to \endabstract still indented?

Tags: macros, environments, etoolbox, xpatch

I'm trying to automatically append "keywords" (defined in the preamble) to the end of the `abstract` environment. The keywords should **not** be flush with the `abstract`, but flush with the body text / left margin.

My aproach is to use:

```
\g@addto@macro\endabstract{\par\noindent{KEYWORDS}\par}
```

but KEYWORDS is still flush with the abstract. The strange thing is, if I remove the `\par` after KEYWORDS, then the alignment is correct, but I need glue space below KEYWORDS (so `\\` isn't an option).

I also overwrote the `quotation` environment (which is used by `abstract`) using:

```
\renewenvironment{quotation}{START}{STOP}
```

and apparently KEYWORDS is outside STOP, so I don't know why it's still indented.

I've tried `etoolbox` and `xpatch` packages too (see below). I'm thinking it has something to do with "modes" or groups but I don't know enough, and I thought `\par` escaped the local group and mode, or something...

Anyways, thanks in advance.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\endabstract{\par\noindent{KEYWORDS}\par}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\AtEndEnvironment{abstract}{\par\noindent{KEYWORDS}\par}

%\usepackage{xpatch}
%\xapptocmd{\endabstract}{\par\noindent{KEYWORDS}\par}{}{}

%\renewenvironment{quotation}{START}{STOP}

\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}
  \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: MWE result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it outside the group of the abstract environment

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\endabstract{\gdef\tmp{\par\noindent{KEYWORDS}\par}\aftergroup\tmp}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\AtEndEnvironment{abstract}{\par\noindent{KEYWORDS}\par}

%\usepackage{xpatch}
%\xapptocmd{\endabstract}{\par\noindent{KEYWORDS}\par}{}{}

%\renewenvironment{quotation}{START}{STOP}

\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}
  \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bless your soul. Since I already had a macro `\makekeywords` which only printed the first `\par` and they keyword stuff if any keywords were given, I adapted your solution to: `\g@addto@macro\endabstract{\aftergroup\makekeywords\aftergroup\bigbreak}`.

Answer (score 2):

With the upcoming LaTeX kernel, due to be released in October, you can use a 'hook' to achieve this. (You'll need to run e.g. pdflatex-dev at present for this to work: that uses the pre-release version of the kernel.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AddToHook{env/abstract/after}{KEYWORDS\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}
  \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I left you to harvest the hook rep points:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I recycled Joseph's text ;-)